# Why is it possible for a generic class to implement interface with different type parameters?

Tags: java

For example like in this section

```
interface MyGenericsI<A, B, C>{
    public A getA();
    public B getB();
    public C getC();
}

abstract class MyGenerics<D> implements MyGenericsI{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the fields or methods that make use of the class' generic type(s) might be unrelated to the methods of the interface. Contrived example:

```
public class Company<P> implements List<Employee> {
    public P produceProduct();
    public Employee get(int index) { ... }
    ...
}
```

Here, a `Company<P>` is capable of producing products of the generic type `P`, so that you could e.g. create a `Company<Computer>` that makes computers. However, a company also has employees, so you could make it implement the methods of `List<Employee>` in order to access the employees of the company (composition would be better in this example, though).